# Ban when sending messages in telegrams cl

Tags: c#, telegram

I tried on 3 phone numbers. The error is PHONE_NUMBER_BANNED. What do I do not so?

My phone number is banned when using the following code:

```
...
using TeleSharp.TL;
using TeleSharp.TL.Contacts;
using TLSharp.Core;
...
// apild=123456
// apiHash=a646b052c0ffd53e2e650dbd0c213236
//values apild, apiHash get from hyperlink [https://my.telegram.org/apps][1] at registration of phone number

FileSessionStore store = new FileSessionStore();
var client = new TelegramClient(apild, apiHash, store,"session");
Task<bool> t = client.ConnectAsync();
bool result = t.Result;
// my phone number with telegramm client = 79001234567
Task t1 = client.SendCodeRequestAsync("79001234567");
string hash = t1.Result;
// "65695" - code from message in telegramm client, what i get after call procedure SendCodeRequestAsync
Task t3 = client.MakeAuthAsync("79001234567", hash, "65695");
TLUser user2 = t3.Result;
```

after call procedure MakeAuthAsync,  the telegramm client became not available, the message is received in code: InvalidOperationException: PHONE_NUMBER_BANNED

Comment: Sounds like you should have opened up a support ticket with telegram.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the phone number was always the same in your case, even when you tried with other ones. That's because you used a FileSessionStore! Use FakeSessionStore and you are good to go with your remaining 2 numbers. Your first one is banned, so just don't use it.